# Conditional statement not redirecting like it should

Tags: python-2.7, conditional-statements

I'm new to python and I working on a stript that gets user input to redirect to another part of the program. I'm using a conditional statement to either go back or exit. But when I press the key to continue it exits. Please help

```
def infoMenu():
a = '''
    1 = Volume Information
    2 = Volume Status
    3 = Display Peer Status
    4 = CTDB Status
    5 = CTDB Ip
    6 = Display CTDB config file
 '''
print a
a = raw_input('Enter your option: ')

if a == '1':
        option = raw_input('Please enter name of vol: ')
        subprocess.call(['gluster vol ', option, 'info'], shell=False)

elif a == '2':
   option = raw_input('Please enter name of vol: ')
   subprocess.call(['gluster vol ', option, 'status'], shell=False)

elif a == '3':
   subprocess.call(['lvdisplay'], shell=False)
   answer = raw_input('Press 0 to go back or any to exit (default[0]): ')

   if answer == '0':
       printOptions()
   else:
       exit()

elif a == '4':
    option = raw_input('Please enter name of vol')
    subprocess.call(['gluster vol ', option, 'info'], shell=False)

elif a == '5':
    option = raw_input('Please enter name of vol')
    subprocess.call(['gluster vol ', option, 'info'], shell=False)
else:
    exit()
```

I'm talking about condition statement 3 when I press 0 its suppose to go back to the beginning menu and anything else should exit. What am I doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tracing your code:

1. function `infoMenu()` is run
2. if the user enters "3" (return)
3. your `subprocess.call` is run
4. then user is asked for a new input

After this your code and your description don't seem to match, because if the user enters "0", your calling some other function (which isn't included) called "printOptions()"

A super simple fix (that would break if you ever `return`) would be to re-call `infoMenu` in place of your `printOptions` call, but I strongly suspect you would be better off better off rewriting.

If I where trying to do what you described (using something like your style) I would do:

```
def infoMenu():
    def thing1():
        pass #do_somethings()

    def thing2():
        #do_someotherthings()
        user_input = raw_input('Press 0 to go back or any to exit (default[0]): ')
        if (len(user_input)==0) or (user_input == '0'):
            return
        else:
            exit()
    a="""
    1 = thing1
    2 = thing2
    """
    print a
    user_input = raw_input('Enter your option')
    if user_input == '1':
        thing1()
    if user_input == '2':
        thing2()

while 1:
    infoMenu()
```

Comment: @eric look at the bit that goes len() == 0, that is to match a (return) alone.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting everything inside the function to a

```
def function()
    while True:
         everything here
```

and then change

```
    if answer == '0':
         pass
    else:
         break
```

also, if you do this, change the exit() at the end to break.

Your problem is that the function is only called once, and thus all the conditionals are run  only once, and does not revert back to one.

Comment: I'm sorry everything is actually in the function. I just formated on here wrong.

Comment: I have printOptions delclared in another file. I've imported that file into this file, but still getting errors that it can't find printOptions.

Comment: Last question in this example how do I add a default value so if the hit enter it would assign the default automatically